# Volatile to be used with Concurrent Collection?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, thread-safety, concurrenthashmap

I am developing a metrics store (Map) , which basically collects metrics about some operations such as

- mix
- max
- counter
- timeElapsed[] etc

Here Key is the name of the method and value are metrics about it.

Spring can help me create singleton object of **MetricStore**, i am using **ConcurrentHashMap** to avoid race condition when **multiple REST request comes in parallel**.

My query
 1- Do i need to make MetricStore variable store volatile? to improve the visibility among multiple requests. 2- I am using Map as the base class and ConcurrentHashMap as Implemetnation, does it affect as Map is not ThreadSafe.
 -

```
@Component
class MetricStore{
    public Map<String, Metric> store = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    //OR  public volatile Map<String, Metric> store = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
}

@RestController
class MetricController{
    @Autowired
    private MetricStore metricStore;

    @PostMapping(name="put")
    public void putData(String key, Metric metricData) {
        if(metricStore.store.containsKey(key)) {
            // udpate data
        }
        else {
            metricStore.store.put(key, metricData);
        }
    }

    @PostMapping(name="remove")
    public void removeData(String key) {
        if(metricStore.store.containsKey(key)) {
            metricStore.store.remove(key);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: re: _"Map is not ThreadSafe"_ – [java.util.Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) isn't threadsafe or non-threadsafe, it's just an interface to some underlying implementation.

Comment: Thanks @kaan for the comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do i need to make MetricStore variable store volatile?

No, because you are not changing the value of `store` (i.e. `store` can be marked as `final` and the code should still compile).

> I am using Map as the base class and ConcurrentHashMap as Implemetnation, does it affect as Map is not ThreadSafe

Because you're using a `ConcurrentHashMap` as the implementation of `Map`, it is thread-safe. If you want the declared type to be more specific, `Map` can be changed to `ConcurrentMap`.

---

The bigger issue here is that you're using `containsKey` before calling `put` and `remove` when you should be using `compute` and `computeIfPresent`, which are atomic operations:

```
@PostMapping(name="put")
public void putData(String key, Metric metricData) {
    metricStore.store.compute(key, (k, v) -> {
        if (v == null) {
            return metricData;
        }

        // update data
    });
}

@PostMapping(name="remove")
public void removeData(String key) {
    metricStore.store.computeIfPresent(key, (k, v) -> null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for enlightening me. Just out of curiosity and for learning. Is compute doing the same job as if i have used synchronized block?

Comment: @DigitalAlchemist It's a bit more complicated than that. See: [ConcurrentHashMap computeIfAbsent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26483476/7294647)