# Building a synchronous map, blocking on individual keys

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to build a repository class, as follows:

```java
public class ResultRepository {

  private Map<String, Result> sqlRepository = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());

  public synchronized Result getResult(String key) {
    Result result = map.get(key);
    if (result == null) {
      result = doAnExpensiveOperation(key));
      map.put(key, result);
    }
    return result;
  }

  ...

}
```

This will work, currently, but will be slow if multiple calls are made to the `getResult` method if the expensive operation is required.

What I want, however, is this:

- Retrieving the result for different keys is non-blocking
- If the result for a specific key has already been created, it is returned immediately
- If the result for a specific key has not already been created, it is generated (via the expensive operation)
- If the result for a specific key has not already been created, but is being generated in a separate thread, the thread waits until the results are created and then returns this.

Is there a pattern I can apply to get this behaviour? I could theoretically have a `Set` of the pending result keys but this seems a bit janky. Maybe the repository could hold `Future<Result>` objects?

Comment: why don't you put  
      result = doAnExpensiveOperation(key));
      map.put(key, result);
    in synchroized block

Comment: You might want to have a look at [ConcurrentHashMap#computeIfAbsent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26481796/1225328).

Comment: @Optional won't this block method calls to other keys that aren't in the map?

Comment: no. it won't. You are not acquiring lock on any key. So that shall be fine. But if you are on jdk8 plus, computeIfAbsent makes more sense

Comment: As others suggested just use `ConcurrentHashMap#computeIfAbsent`. This implementation of map has better concurrency level - meaning you can fetch keyA in threaA and `computeIfAbsent` in threadB - in paralel - at the same time. This implementation does not use a single lock for all access to the hash table -.

Comment: Synchronized HashMap has a drawback that at a time only one thread can read it. Use ConcerrentHashMap, That uses RentrrantReadWrtiteLock which has the capability to read multiple threads at a same time.

Comment: PS. Given the context what you really should be doing here is using a _cache_ not roll-your-own. Look into https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all of this comes with [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

```java
    private Map<String, Result> sqlRepository = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public Result getResult(String key) {
        return sqlRepository.computeIfAbsent(key, this::doAnExpensiveOperation);
    }
```

Comment: A small improvement, that works for _some_ applications, is to do the expensive stuff in a _speculative_ fashion: (1) check the map, and if no result is found then, (2) do the expensive stuff to create a new result _without locking any lock_, then (3) do an atomic `putIfAbsent(key, newResult)`. Finally (4), If it turns out that some other thread duplicated the effort and won the race, then throw away the `newResult`, and use the one that the other guy created. Performance gained by not locking a "expensive" operation can more than offset the performance lost by occasional duplicated effort.